# Need function to convert bool array to int- why doesnt this work?

Tags: convert

Hey I wrote this function to convert an bool array to int:
(Math Lob included):

```
bool b_array[5];

int convertToInt(start_index,stop_index){
    int run=0;
    int result=0;
    for(int id=start_index;id<=stop_index;id++){
        result+=b_array[id] * pow(2.0,run);
        run++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

but it doesnt this work?

Thanks and kind regards 
Nic

Comment: "Does not work" is a poor problem description. Explain what it actually does and what you expected it to do. Provide a minimal but complete test sketch, that shows the problem

Comment: You seem to want to convert an array of bools into the respective integer value, so e.g. `{ false, true, true, false}` into  `0b0110` = 6? Then you should use better casting, so `(int)b_array[id]` and `(int)pow(2.0,run)`. Though it's a weird way to do it, since bitshifting would be more appropriate (`result += b_array[id] ? (1 << run) : 0`) . Also be aware of the numerical limits of your 16-bit signed `int`.

Comment: The pow function returns a float.  Floats are inherently inaccurate.  The index to the array has to be an int.  When you do powers of 2 with pow you don’t actually get 4.  You get 3.9999999 something.  So when that gets truncated it turns into 3 and not the 4 that you want.  Use bit shifting for integer powers of 2 and you won’t have this problem.

Comment: Thank you Guys a lot! It worked like a charm but I could not have made it without you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming little-endian bools (least significant bool first), you should use simple bit-shifting, not floating point power calculations:

```
for(int id=start_index;id<=stop_index;id++){
    result |= b_array[id] ? (1 << run) : 0;
    run++;
}
```

The *ternary* operation (`b_array[id] ? (1 << run) : 0`) means:

- If `b_array[id]` is true,  then

  - Or `result` with 1 left-shifted `run` times and store in `result`
- otherwise

  - Or `result` with 0 and store the result (no-operation).

Comment: You can simplify this in C++ because bool value promoted to an integer is 0 or 1. So `(b_array[id] << run)` can be used. In C there is no bool data type, so something like `((b_array[id] !=0) << run)` should be used. And i like for example `result = (result<<1) | b_array[id];` more (it can be `result = result*2 + b_array[id]` too)

Comment: Thank you for your Solution and your explaination, it worked on first try like a charm! Thank you a lot, I could not have solved that without your help!